# Having to refresh twice to get one certain column of data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2019

I am running a macro on excel, and for some reason, the "Hours" tab doesn't seem to run if I press my macro once. But if I click my macro twice, it populates. My code is the following

```
Sub Refresh()
'
' Refresh Macro
'

'
    Sheets("P DB").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("Cn DB").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    *Sheets("Years DB - CY").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False*
    Sheets("E DB").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("Template").Select
    Calculate
End Sub
```

This code:
    `Sheets("Years DB - CY").Select
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` is what is running twice. FYI, Years DB - CY has a password and is connected to a server. So it should be able to refresh and ask for a password for the server each time.
Any help would be great! Thank you so much

Comment: Delete from `Select // .Selection` from each line and subsequent line (`sheets().listobject.`), plus the `select` before `calculate` ... that'll be the first big help.

Comment: What is in the Hours tab?  Is it a dependent formula?

Comment: sorry my "hours" are on the template page. It is a dependent formula that relies on my "Years DB - CY"